# How can I make PuTTY compatible with Solaris?

Tags: bash, terminal, solaris, putty

I'm connecting to a Solaris machine from WinXP using PuTTY.

When I try to use the NumPad keys for editing a command in Bash (Home, End, Delete) a ~ character is instead printed to the console. Relevant envirnoment parameters as follows:

```
MACHTYPE=sparc-sun-solaris
SHELL=/bin/bash
HOSTTYPE=sparc
OSTYPE=solaris
TERM=xterm
```

**Can I configure PuTTY to get the NumPad keys working?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The path of least resistance is to tell your shell on the Solaris box what the escape sequences sent by PuTTY mean. You see a `~` because these keys emit an escape sequence like `​␛[3~` where ​`␛` is the escape character (`\e`, ASCII 27). Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by one of the keys so that the ​`␛` character is inserted literally, followed by the other characters. Then define bindings in the relevant file, which for bash is `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line     # Home
"\e[4~": end-of-line           # End
"\e[5~": beginning-of-history  # PageUp
"\e[6~": end-of-history        # PageDown
"\e[3~": delete-char           # Delete
"\e[2~": quoted-insert         # Insert
"\eOD": backward-word          # Ctrl+Left
"\eOC": forward-word           # Ctrl+Right
```

Answer (score 0):

Install a terminfo entry (this can be done in your home directory if you do not have root access; you may need to set the `TERMINFO` variable) corresponding to the actual keys sent by putty. `TERM=vt220` or `vt420` might actually be close enough, but then you lose color.

[This page](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/terminfo.html) has some that might work - install terminfo entries with `tic`, and if necessary you can get termcap data with `infocmp -C`.

If this doesn't work, you could experiment with different settings for function keys in the putty settings: if it's just home and end that don't work, try xterm - if nothing works, maybe try SCO ANSI and then set the terminfo to e.g. something corresponding to e.g. freebsd console which uses the same keys.